# Catel application initialization

Tags: catel

I'm looking into Catel. I started following along in the Getting Started for WPF Developers. I create the initial project using the template and run it. All well and good.

Then I take a detailed look at the generated source files. I see references to DataWindow, StyleHelper, and ViewModelBase. And I run in the debugger and watch the Catel debug output, stepping so that I can see *when* things happen.

And it is all magical.

The view manager somehow runs and registers the MainWindow. And the ViewModelFactory is invoked to create MainWindowViewModel, and the MainWindow DataContext gets set.

How does this all happen? I am missing the documentation that puts together for me the sequence of events when an application starts. I am reluctant to take it on faith, and reluctant to dive into the giant code base without an inkling of where to start. I have read the CodeProject articles and the intro part of the documentation.

Is this driven off of the behaviors some way? How are they invoked? I just can't find the thread that starts me on my way.

Aside: I look at Catel because I found myself implementing a *ton* of plumbing for a significant MVVM application, and decided that someone else had already solved this problem.

Thanks for any leads. (And thanks, Geert. This is a significant work.)

-reilly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for advanced information of the inner workings. I think [this part](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/UserControl+-+under+the+hood) of the documentation might be of interest for you.

It might not provide all information you are looking for, but it should provide some.

About some basic questions:

1) The startup windows is defined in App.xaml (that's standard WPF)
2) Since it derives from DataWindow, it uses WindowLogic => LogicBase. The LogicBase uses the *IViewModelLocator* to find the right view model based on naming conventions (all documented)
3) Then the *IViewModelFactory* will instantiate the vm (using dependency injection) and return it to the logic which will set it as datacontext.

Note that as the advanced documentation tells you, Catel injects an additional layer to make a difference between the outside datacontext and the VM datacontext (of a window or user control content).

ps. I really recommend starting to use the latest prereleases via NuGet. Catel 4.0 (will be released very soon) is nearly feature complete and will prevent you from a lot of breaking changes that you have to go through (and it is of course much better :-))

Comment: Thanks, Geert. It never occurred to me that the view lifetime events would be used to run the injection logic. Thanks for the advice on 4.0. We'll run with Catel and I'll let you know when our app is released. Best regards.